# how to make html forms require input before submitting query?

Tags: html, frontend

I'm just getting started with web design and it may be a silly question. I haven't added JavaScript code yet, but what I need is that all the options/forms require input before the query is submitted, otherwise to get highlighted in red. Any help would be great.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

   <form>

       <label for="value1">Example1</label>
       <select id="value1" required>
           <option value="">--Select an option--</option>
           <option value="opt1">1</option>
           <option value="opt2">2</option>

       </select>

       <label for="value2">Example2</label>
       <select id="value2" required>
           <option value="">--Select an option--</option>
           <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
           <option value="Superior">Superior</option>           
       </select>
   </form>

   <label for="date1">date1</label>
   <input type="date" id="firstDate" required>

   <label for="date2">date2</label>
   <input type="date" id="secondDate" required>

   <label for="value3">example3</label>
   <input type="number" id="exampleNumber" required>

   <button type="button" id="button1" required>button1</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: *"...what I need is that all the options/forms require input before the query is submitted"* does that input must be filled with **any** text (even a space) or it must have some other verification.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: the first 2 forms require input from a dropdown menu, the next two require dates and the last one is a number `type="number"`.

Comment: @SLaks Great! That's what I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting like this:

The below given code can be used to validate each and each field more specifically.

Also i have added `:focus` selector in order to highlight if the input data is not given.If the **input data is not given it will be highlighted in red**.

```js
 function  validate(){          
              if(document.rform.fname.value==""){
             alert("Enter Your First Name");
             document.rform.fname.focus();
             return false;
         }        
         if(document.rform.lname.value==""){
             alert("Enter Your Last Name");
             document.rform.lname.focus();
             return false;
         }        
         if(document.rform.address.value==""){
             alert("Enter Your address");
             document.rform.address.focus();
             return false;
         }           
        var val = document.getElementById('mobilenumber').value;
        if (val.length < 10 || val.length > 12 ) {
        alert("Enter a valid phone number")
        return false; // keep form from submitting
        }    

        if(document.rform.city.value==""){
             alert("Enter your city name");
             document.rform.city.focus();
             return false;
         }
         
         
              if(document.rform.pincode.value==""){
           alert("Enter a valid pin number");
           document.rform.pincode.focus();
           return false;
          }        
   
       if(document.rform.email.value==""){
                alert("Enter your Mail Id");
             document.rform.email.focus();
             return false;
       }
         var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
           if(document.rform.email.value.match(mailformat))
          {
         document.rform.email.focus();
         return true;
            }
           else
            {
           alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
              document.rform.email.focus();
            return false;
            }
   return true;
    }
```

```css
.inputs:focus{
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ff0000;
        border-color: #ff0000;
        outline: none !important;
}
```

```html
 <form method="POST" name="rform" action=" "  onsubmit="return(validate());">

    <label for="right-label" class="right inline">First Name</label>
    <input class="inputs" type="text" id="right-label" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" requried>
    <br>
    <label for="right-label" class="right inline">Last Name</label>
    <input   class="inputs" type="text" id="right-label" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" requried>
        <br>

    <label for="right-label" class="right inline">Address</label>
    <input  class="inputs" type="text" id="right-label" placeholder="Address" name="address" requried>
        <br>

    <label for="right-label" class="right inline">City</label>
    <input  class="inputs" type="text" id="right-label" placeholder="City" name="city" requried>
        <br>

    <label for="right-label" class="right inline">Pin Code</label>
    <input  class="inputs" type="number" id="right-label" placeholder="Pincode" name="pincode" requried> 
        <br>

    <label for="right-label" class="right inline">E-Mail</label>
    <input  class="inputs" type="email" id="right-label" placeholder="Mail Id" name="email"  requried>
        <br>

    <label for="right-label" class="right inline">Mobile Number</label>
    <input  class="inputs" type="number" id="mobilenumber" placeholder="Mobile Number" name="mobile_num"   requried>  
        <br>

    <input type="submit" id="right-label" value="Register" name="submit" >
    <input type="reset" id="right-label" value="Reset">

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add hidden error class below every input fields. You can validate the form using javascript and jquery. If the input is wrong you can make the error class appear.

HTML :

```
<form method="POST" id="register_form" action=" " autocomplete="off">  

    <label for="right-label" class="right inline">First Name</label>
    <input class="inputs" type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
    <small id="fn_error" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
    <br>
    <label for="right-label" class="right inline">Last Name</label>
    <input   class="inputs" type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
    <small id="ln_error" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
    <br>        
    <input type="submit" id="right-label" value="Register" name="submit" >
    <input type="reset" id="right-label" value="Reset">   

</form>
```

JS :

```
$('#register_form').on("submit",function () {
        var firstName= $("#firstName");
        var lastName= $("#lastName");        
        var status = false;

        if (firstName.val() == "") {
            firstName.addClass("borer-danger");
            $("#fn_error").html("<span class='text-danger'>Please Enter Email</span>");
            status = false;
        } else {
            firstName.removeClass("border-danger");
            $("#fn_error").html("");
            status = true
        }
        if (lastName.val() == "") {
            lastName.addClass("borer-danger");
            $("#ln_error").html("<span class='text-danger'>Please Enter Last Name</span>");
            status = false;
        } else {
            lastName.removeClass("border-danger");
            $("#ln_error").html("");
            status = true
        }
        if (status == true) {
            alert("Ready");
        }
    })
```